# In the phrase, "The big shots up at the church", is 'up at" a two word preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I'm struggling with how to diagram 'up at'.  Is this a two word or complex preposition or something else?

Comment: I lately lost a preposition:
It hid, I thought, beneath my chair.
And angrily I cried: "Perdition!
Up from out of in under there!"
Correctness is my vade mecum,
And straggling phrases I abhor;
And yet I wondered: "What should he come
Up from out of in under for?" -- Morris Bishop

Comment: (They are two separate prepositions, and what you have is a sort of recursive prepositional phrase.  This is fairy common -- I'm often up to no good, for instance, especially when the boss is after me to get down to work.  But, look up in the sky!  It's Superman!)

Comment: The precise meaning of 'up' here is impossible to pin down. If the church is on a hill, 'up at the church' may be best identified as two separate prepositions, with the phrase analysed as a deleted form of say 'up the hill, at the church'. We may compare 'down at the docks'. But sometimes, 'up' can have the metaphorical sense 'at the place of importance'. 'Up town'. 'Up at the palace / villa / hall'.  'Up at university'.  And to me,  it's more tempting to see 'up at' here as a single lexeme.

Answer (score 2):

Treat it as a single preposition for the purposes of diagramming.

It reads like a *phrasal preposition*, or a preposition formed of two or more words ([Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2835&dq=%22phrasal%20preposition%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu0ZeQiezhAhWlmuAKHQ_YD3wQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q=%22phrasal%20preposition%22&f=false)). Fowler refers to these as *compound prepositions* ([example: "outside of"](https://books.google.com/books?id=AvmzBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Fowler%20modern%20english%20usage%202009&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN9-jaiuzhAhXllOAKHfodBRUQuwUILTAA#v=onepage&q=%22compound%20preposition%22&f=false)).

There are examples of diagrammers treating these as a single preposition. For example, in [this model](http://www.german-latin-english.com/diagram2.htm) "according to" is written on the same branch without further distinction. The author, Eugene R. Moutoux, notes:

> If you counted, you may have missed the seventh preposition, *according to*, a compound preposition. Some other compound prepositions are because of, on account of, except for, out of, instead of, in spite of, and next to.

In another diagram, Moutoux depicts "[on account of](http://www.german-latin-english.com/diagramamend15.htm)" on a single branch and calls it a *phrasal preposition*.

Comment: Much the same can be said of almost any conventional phrase that functions the way a PP does, e.g, _with the assistance of, under the auspices of, for the benefit of, with sincere admiration and thanks to,_ etc. If they're all bunched up together in speech, they're basically functioning as a single word.

Comment: 'into' has already consciously transitioned into a single preposition, but 'out of' has not...unless 'outta' counts.

Comment: English loves to stack prepositions: e.g., "We gotta get on up out of here."

Answer (score -1):

In this context, "up" is an [adverb of position](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/up).

> Up as an adverb
>
> We use *up* as an adverb to talk about movement towards a higher position, value, number or level:
>
> She put the books **up** on the highest shelf.

[Here](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-place/) is another web page about adverbs of place in general. Admittedly it doesn't list "up" except in the phrase "up there", but it does list "down" (in its list of adverbs of place that are also prepositions), and "up" is similar grammatically.

> Used as an adverb of place, modifying a verb: Mary **fell down**.

Comment: If you're going to put an answer differing significantly from that of J Lawler, it behoves you to add (linked and attributed) supporting reference, and from a grammar or academic article rather than a dictionary.